# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Mean_μg_L'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

[image]

Why am I getting this error if the column name exists.

I have tried everything. I am out of ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `AttributeError` is raised at the first column with a name containing a mathematical symbol (`µ`), I would suggest you these two solutions :

1. Use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) right before the loop to get rid of this special character

   ```
   df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("_\wg_", "_ug_", regex=True)
   #change df to Table_1_1a_Tarawa_Terrace_System_1975_to_1985
   ```

Then inside the loop, use `row.Mean_ug_L`, .. instead of `row.Mean_µg_L`, ..

2. Use `row["col_name"]` (*highly recommended*) to refer to the column rather than `row.col_name`

   ```
    for index, row in Table_1_1a_Tarawa_Terrace_System_1975_to_1985.iterrows():
        SQL_VALUES_Tarawa = (row["Chemicals"], rows["Contamminant"], row["Mean_µg_L"], row["Median_µg_L"], row["Range_µg_L"], row["Num_Months_Greater_MCL"], row["Num_Months_Greater_100_µg_L"])
        cursor.execute(SQL_insert_Tarawa, SQL_VALUES_Tarawa)
        counting = cursor.rowcount
        print(counting, "Record added")
        conn.commit()
   ```